# What is a Stereotype in Unified modelling language?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

My question is about a UML keyword. When I'm learning software engineering class diagrams, I met this **[Stereotype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotype_(UML))** keyword. I searched through the web, but I can't get a clear idea of what it means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A stereotype is a way of "painting" UML elements. Take classes for example. Anything can be reduced to a class. And that would generally be fine. But with a large number of different classes your domain gets crowded. So you stereotype classes. This is a way of painting/badging them. E.g. in a car factory you have lots of parts (classes). And you would like to group some as `<<motor>>`, `<<mounting material>>`, `<<frame>>`, etc.

In order to use a stereotype you need to define a profile. The profile allows to attach individual properties (formerly *tagged values*) to each stereotype. E.g. for the `<<frame>>` you'd like to have a `material` property which can take "plastic" and "metal" and the like.